# how customize User validator to accept whitespaces

Tags: django, validation, django-models, customization

I want have custom validation for User to create name user with whitespaces in name. I do this like below but, I create User2 and change regex expression but it not changed validation conditions, it's not work. Have anybody idea why or how instead of I can do it?

models

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.validators import UnicodeUsernameValidator


class MyUnicodeUsernameValidator(UnicodeUsernameValidator):
    print('test My')
    regex = r'^[\d]'
    message = _(
        'Enter a valid username. This value may contain only letters, '
        'numbers, and @/./+/-/_ characters.'
    )
    flags = 0


class User2(User):
    username_validator = MyUnicodeUsernameValidator()
    print(username_validator)
```

view

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import User2
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from blog.models import Article




class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User2
        fields = ("username",)

def sign_up(request):
    context = {}

    form = MyUserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'accounts/index.html')
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request,'registration/sign_up.html', context)
```

Comment: You created a new validator, and you attached it as a class attribute, but that will not change the validation of existing fields...

Comment: Furthermore because `User` is not an abstract model, you now have two tables: a table with only a `ForeignKey` from `User2` to `User` and the `User` model.

Answer (score 2):

This approach will not work for several reasons. The first one is that you here make a subclass, which will be implemented as a *sub-model*: an extra model with no fields. But even if `User` was an abstract model, it would not work. The `User` model has a [**`username`** field [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L315-L333) with a validator:

> ```
> class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
>     # …
>     username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()
>
>     username = models.CharField(
>         _('username'),
>         max_length=150,
>         unique=True,
>         help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
>         validators=[username_validator],
>         error_messages={
>             'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
>         },
>     )
> ```

but this is not as a "*indirect* reference" to the `username_validator` at the class level: a reference to the `UnicodeUsernameValidator` object, so even if you alter the validator, then that does not changes the fields already constructed.

I think the best way to implement this is [*Specifying a custom user model* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model). Making a user model that you will use as user model. You thus define a class:

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username_validator = MyUnicodeUsernameValidator()
    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text='Some helptext that describes what are valid usernames',
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    # …
```

It will however require extra work (the steps specified in the documentation) to define the other fields, the manager, etc.

While you can do this, it might not be a good idea to allow spaces in the username. Usernames are sometimes used in URIs, and since whitespace is percentage encoded to `%20`, that will result in "*ugly*" URIs.

Comment: This project I treat as a lesson to know some things. I use Your advises and example to get my own opinion is worth to do that, also for a cost of "ugly" urls. Thanks one again for a help :)